# Error: Program type already present: com.google.gson.annotations.Expose

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After i updated my project to latest version, (Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.1 and Gradle to version 4.6), including supporting last sdk version (28). i can't run my project and throws 4 errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\72, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\73, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\86, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\87, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\88, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\89
```

and this error

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\72, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\73, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\86, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\87, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\88, G:\MoodyProjects\my-city-new\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\89
```

and this error

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
```

and this error

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.gson.annotations.Expose
```

here is my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

/*Note see */

buildscript {
repositories {
    //maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

/*


repositories {
//maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}
*/
/*dor camera view libary*/
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.2'
            }
        }
    }
}
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "co.my_city.new_android"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    multiDexEnabled true


}

/*Note: Android Studio disables ProGuard when using Instant Run.
If you need code shrinking for incremental builds, try the experimental Gradle shrinker.*/
/* Link : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#gradle-shrinker*/
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        /*To enable code shrinking with ProGuard, add minifyEnabled true to the
        appropriate build type in your build.gradle file*/
        minifyEnabled false
        /*To enable resource shrinking, set the shrinkResources property to true in
        your build.gradle file (alongside minifyEnabled for code shrinking). For example:*/
        //shrinkResources true ;
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'


implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'


implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.1'
implementation 'com.github.charbgr:authmanager:1.0'
implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.2.2'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'




implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0' // restful

implementation files('libs/gson-1.7.1.jar')

implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0' // matrial dialogs  ;
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0' // RTPersmisions

//compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'
//compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0' // runtime permsions
implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:1.4.1'
//compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
/*compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}*/

implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}


allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I dont know how to fix this error i looked if someone else had the same error but could not find a solution, i cleaned and rebuild my project but didn't help.

Comment: Just try to clean the project, I think will help.

Comment: as i said in the question, clean and rebuild already been done but error keeps appearing when i try to run the app

Comment: See My updated Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this line to your build.gradle.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
}
```

Comment: yesterday i added this line to the build.gradle(app) and the app run perfectly.
but for some reason today while im trying to run the app again, the exact same errors appeared again but after cleaning, rebuilding and invalidate catches/restart the errors disappeared and the app back running as well.

Comment: Yes because of that I told you first to clean the project.